How do I configure Microsoft Security DevOps' ESLint scan to produce the correct command-line output?
I am trying to configure MSDO's ESLint scan according to the instructions here:
https://github.com/microsoft/security-devops-action/wiki#ESLint-options
I would like to reproduce the command here(lifted from the current logs, made without custom configuration) as a starting point:
D:\a\_msdo\packages\node_modules\eslint\eslint.cmd
  --no-eslintrc 
  --config D:\a\_msdo\packages\node_modules\eslint/node_modules/@microsoft/eslint-plugin-sdl/config/required.js 
  --ext .js
  --ext .ts
  --ignore-pattern *.d.ts 
  --format D:\a\_msdo\packages\node_modules\eslint\node_modules\@microsoft\eslint-formatter-sarif\sarif.js --output-file D:\a\1\s\.gdn\.r\eslint\001\eslint.sarif **/*.{js,ts}

These options in the MSDO config do not clearly associate to the available command line flags. At the moment I have this:
{
  "tools": [
    {
      "tool": {
        "name": "ESLint",
        "version": "Latest"
      },
      "arguments": {
        "DisableDefaultConfigurationFile": true,
        "ResolvePluginsRelativeTo": "",
        "ConfigurationFile": "D:\a\_msdo\packages\node_modules\eslint/node_modules/@microsoft/eslint-plugin-sdl/config/required.js",
        "Environments": "",
        "Extensions": [".js", ".ts"],
        "Globals": "",
        "Parser": "",
        "ParserOptions": "",
        "AdditionalRulesDirectories": "",
        "Plugins": "",
        "Rules": "",
        "Fix": "",
        "FixDryRun": "",
        "FixTypes": "",
        "ExclusionsFilePath": "$(BuildSourcesDirectory)/.eslintignore"
        "DisableExclusions": "",
        "ExclusionPatterns": "*.d.ts",
        "Quiet": "",
        "MaxWarnings": "",
        "ExitOnFatalError": "",
        "OutputFile": "D:\a\1\s\.gdn\.r\eslint\001\eslint.sarif",
        "OutputFormat": "D:\a\_msdo\packages\node_modules\eslint\node_modules\@microsoft\eslint-formatter-sarif\sarif.js",
        "DisableInlineConfig": "",
        "ReportUnusedDisableDirectives": "",
        "Cache": "",
        "CacheLocation": "",
        "Debug": "",
        "Help": "",
        "Targets": "**/*.{js,ts}"
      }
    }
  ]
}


And what I have right now gets me this output:

##[error]NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
##[error]MSDO CLI exited with an error exit code: 1

Can anyone provide some guidance on how to use this config to produce the known good outcome above?
I've tried a ton of different configurations but at this point I am kinda guessing at everything and I can't figure out why I'm getting a null reference error.
I'm also unable to create a microsoft-security-devops tag and apply it, if anyone can help me out with that part...

I have at least resolve the null reference error issue.
If anyone else is having the same battle, try setting all slashes/backslashes consistently. You can't just take a command line output that worked and feed the arguments back in - you have to standardize on '/' or '\' for all config parameters, according to the type of build agent running the pipeline.

Thanks for sharing the answer. Maybe, you can accept it by yourself. It could be also helpful for other people who are looking for a solution of the similar questions. @LincolnLourens
